# Encoding and Servlet API: setContentType or setCharacterEncoding

Tags: java, servlets, character-encoding

Just wonder what is behind the scene.
Actually it seems that we can set the encoding with:

- `response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8")`
- `response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8")`

What is the difference?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#setContentType%28java.lang.String%29) is pretty clear about the difference:

> `void setCharacterEncoding(String charset)`
>   Sets the character encoding (MIME charset) of the response being sent to the client, for example, to UTF-8. If the character encoding has already been set by `setContentType(java.lang.String)` or `setLocale(java.util.Locale)`, this method overrides it. **Calling `setContentType(java.lang.String)` with the String of `text/html` and calling this method with the String of UTF-8 is equivalent with calling `setContentType` with the String of `text/html; charset=UTF-8`**.

---

> `void setContentType(String type)`
>   Sets the content type of the response being sent to the client, if the response has not been committed yet. **The given content type may include a character encoding specification, for example, `text/html;charset=UTF-8`**.

Comment: I am missing something : `setContentType("text/html"); setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");` is equivalent to `setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");` or just `setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");` will do ?